# What's the easiest way to set a variable to be what the user types as a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot that takes commands. I need it to set a variable to be equal to the `int` you type in, but I'm having trouble thinking of the solution. Currently it looks something like this:

```
switch(args[0]){
    case "test":

        if(args[1] == typeof 'number')
        {
            Functions.noOfPacks = args[1];
        }
```

This doesn't work, however. Ideally, I want to be able to type `!pack 2` and set the variable to 2.
I would do it through user input, but I don't want the bot to wait for input, as the commands won't work anymore. I know the function (in another file) works because it will loop twice if I set the variable to be 2 beforehand, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule whatever a user types in will be read by your code as a String.

Example:

```js
document.querySelector('#box').onkeyup = function (e) {
  if (e.code !== 'Enter') return;

  const v = this.value
  
  if (Number.isNaN(+v)) {
    console.log(`${v} is not a number`)
    this.value = '' //clear the input when it is not a number
  } else {
    console.log(`${v} is a number`)
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="box">Type something in there and press Enter</label>
<input type="text" id="box" />
```